# How prevent click in event press Gestures Ionic2?

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to implement a `press` option on a `button` that already has a `click` event.

Is it possible to avoid `click` if the `press` occurs?

For in my tests the `click` is triggered even if the `press` has happened before. I tried to include `event.preventDefault()` in `press` event.

[<kbd>Example in Plunker</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/RKfOdkz4nUcYz5KWS4Vw?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the (click) handler, try using (tap).

Answer (score 0):

you can add

> return false

in the (click) function or can simply use

> (tap)

to avoid this problem.
I hope it helped :)

Comment: `return false` in `click`, not work! Since `press` occurs before the `click` event in the scenario where the two events occur, and `return false` in the `press` event also does not prevent `click`. [Here is an updated example with `return false` in `press` event. It does not work.](http://plnkr.co/edit/UiEXemMMwztm4gml0n09?p=preview)